# Trouble in adding a UITableview as subview of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Please help me to resolve this issue as I am struck up due to this issue.

I have a view controller named `Mapviewcontroller`.

This `Mapviewcontroller` consists of map view (all created using storyboard). On click of the pins in the map, I should show a `UIView` as a `popupview` (This is my custom `UIView` named `mappopoverView`).

This `popoverview` should show some location lists too, so I used a `UITableView` called `maplocationTableview`.

This `maplocationtableview` I created & designed using storyboard in `Mapviewcontroller` and initially set hidden. On click of map pins, I tried to add my tableview as subview but it is not working.

My code is:

```
  self. maplocationtableview.hidden = NO;
  MappopoverView *alertView = [[MappopoverView alloc] initTableview:self.maplocationtableview];

  alertView.delegate = self;
  [alertView show];

  [self. maplocationtableview setDelegate:self];
  [self. maplocationtableview setDatasource:self];
  [self. maplocationtableview reloadData];
```

But the tableview is not added as subview and also `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not invoked. Could any one please help me with a solution.Sorry if my question is confusing.

Comment: In `MappopoverView` you have to use *addSubview* method like [self addSubView:mappopoverview];

Comment: in the initTableView method sorry i forgot....

Comment: pardon me,i did not understand

Comment: Did you added tableview as subview of popoverview ?

Comment: Yes its added,if i create a UItablview programmatically and repeat the above code no issue but if using the tableview created from storyboard ,i am facing the issue.

Comment: did you make connection on IB?

Comment: connections means i hope  setting delegate and datasource.Its done

Comment: did you set Referencing Outlets for maplocationtableview ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create IBOutlet of **MappopoverView** and your **maplocationtableview** in your  **mapviewcontroller** and then you have to just add your **maplocationtableview** in **MappopoverView** outlet using *addSubview* 
also make sure you have IBOutlet mapview SO. you have three IBOutlets now

> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
>
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CUPopOverView *popoverview;
>
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CUTableview
>   *maplocationtableview;

Please Go through following code: mapviewcontroller

viewDidLoad

```
self.mapview.delegate = self;
    [self.mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];


    [self.popoverview addSubview:self.maplocationtableview];



- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    if(![self.popoverview isDescendantOfView:view])
        [view addSubview:self.popoverview];


}


-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LAT, LONG);
    [self.mapview  addAnnotation:point];
}
```